# Finding a string in python and writing it in another file

Tags: python

I have written a function in Python to find a string and send the data in the line at which the string is found to another function to store the data. But some how I dont get any error nor it does what I would like it to do.

I have attached the code snippet

```
def Find_Member_Functions(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File):
 Member_Function_Keyword = '( '
 Found_Functions = ''
 for line in Opened_Cpp_File:
  if re.match(Member_Function_Keyword, line):
   Found_Functions = Member_Functions(Opened_Cpp_File, line)
   Member_Functions = Member_Functions(Opened_File, Found_Functions)
   print str(Found_Functions)
   else:
    print "No keyword could be matched finding again \n"
   break
 return Found_Functions
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate over `Opened_Cpp_File` twice - why? What is `Member_Functions`? Could you please follow [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?

Comment: You have a trailing space in `Member_Function_Keyword`. In all my limited C++ experience I have never seen a function/method/class initialization written using a space before the first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things dodgy here that I think may be contributing to this.

**Strange thing 1:**

Strangely, when  I even attempt to run this regex, I get an error and I can't see why you do not get this. When I attempt to run this:

```
line = 'hello'
Member_Function_Keyword = "( "
if re.match(Member_Function_Keyword, line):
```

I get: `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis`

This makes me *presume* that your program never gets to your regex. I imagine this is because of the way you strip your string - You end up with nothing in `Iterating_Function` so your regex is never called.

**Strange Thing 2:**

You use break **OUTSIDE** of the `if` statement. Your for loop will break on its first loop regardless of what happens. So, whatever the first line contains will always end the loop so nothing will be returned. However, I find this strange because you say nothing happens *at all*, not even the else statement is printed out. This again leads me to the conclusion that you must have one of the following problems:

- Your regex is wrong. Not likely as no error is produced
- Since no error is produced - regex is never called. This leads me to think either...

  - Your File is empty or something in the strange way you iterate over the file twice is emptying it.

I realise that this is not a solution to your problem however I hope it can help you to debug it. I would defiantly check the contents of your file, check that you are calling `.read()` on your file somewhere, do something about the strange iterations you are doing and finally the indentation on your `break` statements.

**Update Possible Answer**:

Re-looking at your code, I am noticing very strange thigs. Firstly, You Define `Member_Function_Keyword`, then preceed to overwite it by using it in your for loop...

```
for Member_Function_Keyword in Iterating_Function:
```

This means that, for each letter in iterating function, you are saving this letter as `Member_Function_Keyword` and then checking if it is the first letter of the current line which brings me to my next point...

You are removing the lines from your file with this line

```
Iterating_Function =  [line.strip() for line in Opened_Cpp_File]
```

Then, iterating over the lines in the file with the next line. This seems odd.

So, with these strange things taken into account and that fact that you haven't really told us what you want this function to do, I am going to try and make a few presumptions. I am going to presume that you are looking for a bracket at the start of a line in the file. So, here is how you would do that:

```
for line in Opened_Cpp_File:
    if re.match(Member_Function_Keyword, line):
        #Do something here...
        #NOTE, you were doing this:
        #Found_Functions = Member_Functions(Opened_File, line)
        #This is 'recursion' and I can't see why you want it
    else:
        #Do something else
```

Or, if you want to stop when you find a line that contains a bracket:

```
for line in Opened_Cpp_File:
    if re.match(Member_Function_Keyword, line):
        #Do something here...
        break
    else:
        #Do something else
```

Sadly, with the vagueness of the question, I cannot do much more. I hope this will help though.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your wonderful explanation. Yes I was doing so many blunders. My aim was to find the keyword 'blabla(string bla, int bla)' something like this as I wanted to identify if it is a function, if so copy it in another file. This was my aim of this loop. The example I got from some site, I modified it to suit my purpose. Unfortunately its not working. I will try your suggestion and try to update the result

Comment: The code actually deletes the content of the file, yet it doesnt also print the statement  "No keyword could be matched finding again \n"...I will attach the edited code again..

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. It sounds like you could get what you need from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429086/python-regex-to-get-all-text-until-a-and-get-text-inside-brackets). Scroll to the first answer and look at the regular expression groups in the example. @user3652437

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I was able to rectify the issue :) Thanks for the reply !!